# Change single item's icon to another one when clicked in loop / React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have looping through github repos with icon star for each repo links

When I click the  element it should change far fa-star to fas fa-star dynamically

I tried this but it changes all items stars to full ones

```
    const [starState,setStarState] = useState(false);

    <star onClick={()=> setStarState(!starState)}/>

startState ? 
<star onClick={()=> setStarState(!starState)}/> :
<fullStar onClick={()=> setStarState(!starState)}/>
```

Comment: I recently had a similiar issue with my program, its most likely that the state is shared between each element from the loop, please refer to [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: I think each 'Star'-component should have its own 'starState' state variable, instead of storing it in the parent component.
The Star component should be responsible for settings its own state when its being clicked.